# Beamer: drawing a rectangle that does not overlay the navigation bar

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am trying to draw a blue filled rectangle on half of the slide space. However, I do not want it to overlay the navigation bar. The following figures illustrate the current situation:

The title page

[image]

The first slide of the first section. I would like the navigation bar to appear in this one.

[image: I would like the navigation bar to appear in this slide.]

The content of the first section

[image]

Here follows an MWE for this case

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

% To make the navigation bullets appear
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
    \@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!50!black}\insertsectionhead}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]


\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\title{My Presentation}
\author[My short name]{\bfseries My name}
\institute{University}
\date[19/05/15]{\today}

\begin{document}
{   
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][100]
\frame{ % This is the title slide where I'd like to highlight the sections
  \frametitle{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
  \maketitle  
}
}

\section{First section}
    {
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \frame{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue]
  ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node[anchor=center]
  at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertsection}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    }
    }
    \frame{\frametitle{My Frame Title}}\frame{}

\section{Second section}
{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \frame{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue]
  ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node[anchor=center]
  at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertsection}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    }
    }
    \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Third section}
{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \frame{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue]
  ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node[anchor=center]
  at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertsection}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    }
    }\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Conclusion}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

Does someone knows how to proceed in this case?

Best,
Humberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to not have your rectangle cover the header on your slide, you can add a `yshift=-\headheight` to your rectangle. The code in the first section would then look like:

```
\section{First section}
    {
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \frame{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue]
  ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headheight]current page.north east);
\node[anchor=center]
  at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertsection}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    }
    }
```

This will shift the top of the rectangle down and uncover the header. This is what I get with that code:

[image: Blue box shift example]

Answer (score 2):

If you want that the rectangle is shown only on `section` frames, you can use `\AtBeginSection` command which defines how section frames are defined.

And as your rectangle covers the headline, you can place the rectangle on `background` which is drawn before headline.

This way you don't have to insert the code for every section page.

In following code, please note that lines from `\setbeamertemplate{background}` to `\end{frame}` inside `\AtBeginSection` command are inserted into a local scope `{` `}`. Otherwise the background is used in all frames.

Probably a better solution would be to define a new background with `\defbeamertemplate` and later on call it with `\usebeamertemplate` inside `\AtBeginSection` but I do not know how to do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% To make the navigation bullets appear
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
    \@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!50!black}\insertsectionhead}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]


\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    {\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue]
        ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=center]
        at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
        {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
                    \textpdfrender{
                        TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
                        FillColor=white,
                        LineWidth=.1ex,
                    }{\insertsection}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\title{My Presentation}
\author[My short name]{\bfseries My name}
\institute{University}
\date[19/05/15]{\today}

\begin{document}
{   
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][100]
\frame{ % This is the title slide where I'd like to highlight the sections
  \frametitle{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
  \maketitle  
}
}

\section{First section}

\frame{\frametitle{My Frame Title}}
\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Second section}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Third section}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Conclusion}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version: with `\defbeamertemplate`**

Now I've understood how to use a `\defbeamertemplate`. This command serves to define templates and assign them a name for further references.

In previous code, `\AtBeginSection` could be replaced with:

```
\defbeamertemplate{background}{blue half}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue]
        ([yshift=0pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=center]
        at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=0pt]current page.center) 
        {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
                    \textpdfrender{
                        TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
                        FillColor=white,
                        LineWidth=.1ex,
                    }{\insertsection}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    {\setbeamertemplate{background}[blue half]
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
}
```

where, `\defbeamertemplate{background}{blue half}{...}` defines a template for `backgorund` called `blue half` which is later on used in `\AtBeginSection` with
`\setbeamertemplate{background}[blue half]`. Please, note `[]` for introducing name and that the change is locally applied with `{...}` help.