# Background image on right side of Beamer presentation in Hannover theme

Tags: beamer

I am making a presentation in `LaTex` using the Beamer document class. I am using the `Hannover` theme. This has a navigation bar on the left side and the content of the presentation is on the right hand side.

I want to place background image on a slide (or a frame) but only on the right hand side (spanning the entire right hand side *only*). I followed this link --> [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame) . However, part of the image also lies behind the navigation bar (which I do not want). How can I achieve this?

**Edit 1:**
Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}
    \section{A section}
    {
        \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth {../img/cluster-ex-1.png}}%
        \begin{frame}
            \begin{center}
                \LARGE
                    \textit{\textbf{Title of the frame}}            
            \end{center}
        \end{frame}
    }
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result of above latex code]

As you can see, the image also lies behind the navigation bar, which ***I do not want***. I want it to occupy the entire right hand side of the presentation ***only***. How can I do the same?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related question: [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247988/124842)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\makeatletter
    \newlength{\imagewidth}
    \setlength{\imagewidth}{\paperwidth}
    \addtolength{\imagewidth}{-\beamer@sidebarwidth}

    \newlength{\sidebarwidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarwidth}{\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \hspace*{\sidebarwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)